# Can you use your experimental predictor as an outcome variable in a time series statistical model?

Tags: time-series, experiment-design, causality, philosophical

I asked chatGPT and it said that of course I can, but I thought having a human in the loop would be a good idea to confirm.

The main question is: *Can you use your experimental predictor as an outcome variable in a statistical model, but still claim that it is the cause (and not the effect)?*

The specific context:
I work with time series physiological data in media research, I look at how videos affect viewers. I am interested in changes over time and not only the differences averaged across all time points. But I also have survey data, which is one data point averaged across time because it's asked after watching the video.

The typical research design would treat physiology as the outcome, for example do the horror movies genre trigger more electrodermal activity (EDA, measured in second by second changes) than pornography?. See:

```
EDA_1hz ~ VideoGenre
```

But say I have the prediction that emotional arousal will affect a survey question that was asked after watching (e.g., from 1 to 10 how much would you like to watch another video like this?).

I don't want to make electrodermal activity the predictor as one data point because it would lose the time series information, for example I might expect that if a porn video triggers an emotional arousal in a u-shaped pattern (quadratic effect), the viewer will be more likely to wanting to watch another pornographic video but this won't be the case when it's a downwards linear effect... So this wouldn't work:

```
LikelihoodContinueWatching ~ Average_EDA
```

How would you test that?

Could I separately use the linear and quadratic electrodermal values as outcome (DV) and the likelihood of wanting to watch another video (measured from 1 to 10) as the predictor (IV) in the model, see:

```
EDA_1h ~ LikelihoodContinueWatching
```

And if I do this, *can I still claim causality from EDA to the survey question?* Chronologically speaking the viewer first watched the video, then responded to it in electrodermal activity, and then depending on that, they responded the survey question, so the causality is there at the experimental level but not in the model.